# Vectorial derivatives

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this function:
$$y_{t,\tau} = a_{\tau} + \mathbf{b}'_{\tau}\mathbf{x}_t + \mathbf{x}'_tC_{\tau}\mathbf{x}_t$$

where $\prime$ means transposed, $\mathbf{x}_t$ is a $2\times1$ vector (of two stochastic processes) and I guess $\mathbf{a}_{\tau}$ is a scalar function, $\mathbf{b}_{\tau}$ is a $2\times1$ vector-valued function while $C_{\tau}$ is $2\times2$ matrix-valued function (these functions are solutions to certain ODEs).

The derivative (vector/matrix) wrt $\mathbf{x}_t$ should be ($\mathbf{b}_{\tau}+2C_{\tau}\mathbf{x}_t$). Can you demonstrate it?

Comment: The code for `times` is, well… \times`. That said,if $b_\tau$ and $x_t$ are $2\times1$, you can't multiply them. And, yes, for your first question, you can't multiply the matrices in  this order

Comment: the transposed of $b_{\tau}$ is 1x2 and I can multiply it by a 2x1

Comment: I didn't see a transpose???

Comment: $b'_{\tau}$..isn't it?

Comment: @davidpaich you should specify the notation you're assuming. While you're used to see $\mathbf{b}'$ as the transposed of a vector, there are other notations like ${}^T\mathbf{b}$ or $\mathbf{b}^T$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $a_\tau$, $\mathbf{b}_\tau$ and $C_\tau$ do not depend on $\mathbf{x}_\tau$, the result is

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y_{\tau}}{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}_t} = \frac{\mathrm{d}a_\tau}{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}_t} + \frac{\mathrm{d}(\mathbf{b}'_\tau\mathbf{x}_t)}{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}_t} + \frac{\mathrm{d}(\mathbf{x}'_tC_\tau\mathbf{x}_t)}{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}_t} = 0 + \mathbf{b}'_\tau + \mathbf{x}'_tC_\tau + \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}'_t}{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}_t}C_\tau\mathbf{x}_t.
$$